# Byte Buffer To String

Tags: c#, character-encoding, character, arrays, ascii

Reading a Byte buffer:

```
while (...)
{
    builder.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, index, 1));
    ++index;
}
```

I'm getting the following result: "20202020202020202020202057363253304b4358", which looks like ASCII or HTML character codes. What is the best and faster way to obtain the real string out of that value in C#?

Comment: How did you obtain the values in `buffer` to start with? A short but *complete* example would be really helpful here. (Additionally, you shouldn't need to append a single character at a time...)

Comment: The buffer is a result of a DeviceIoControl call, that's why I didn't provide any example, code was veeeery long and quite pointless. Looks like the string is somehow flipped and encoded though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although I think there is something wrong in your code while getting that string, anyway, you can use

```
byte[] buf = SoapHexBinary.Parse("20202020202020202020202057363253304b4358").Value;
var str = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buf);
```

which would return            `W62S0KCX`

**PS:** `SoapHexBinary` is in  *wellknown* `System.Runtime.Remoting.Metadata.W3cXsd2001` namespace :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have the entire buffer available already, then simply try:

```
var myString = Encoding.Default.GetString(byteBuffer);
```